# Graphql: How to map fields that start with number

Tags: graphql

Learning GraphQL right now and having some issue to 'map' object properties.

I am trying to map this object https://data.metromobilite.fr/api/ficheHoraires/json?route=SEM:C&time=1544221514650

*(note: you might change the timestamp to a future one, find it here https://currentmillis.com/)*

Here is the JSON format:

```
{
    "0": {
        "arrets": [],
        "trips": [],
        "prevTime": 1544217780000,
        "nextTime": 1544229600000
    },
    "1": {}
}
```

My code:

```
const SheetType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Sheet",
  fields: () => ({
    arrets: { type: ArretsType },
    trips: { type: TripsType },
    prevTime: { type: GraphQLString },
    nextTime: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
});

const TimeSheetType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "TimeSheet",
  fields: () => ({
    0: { type: SheetType },
    1: { type: SheetType }
  })
});
```

However, I don't know how to map the object since the keys are numbers and it is not possible map fields by numbers (https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Names).

What can I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API will always only return the keys "0" and "1", you can just have two arbitrarily named fields that map back to the keys returned by the API.

```
const TimeSheetType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "TimeSheet",
  fields: () => ({
    zero: {
      type: SheetType,
      resolve: (parent) => parent['0'],
    },
    one: {
      type: SheetType,
      resolve: (parent) => parent['1'],
    },
  })
})
```

On the other hand, if the API could return keys named '2', '3', '4' and so on, the better option would be to change the structure of the data structure to utilize an array instead. In this case, you would omit the `TimeSheetType` entirely, and just return a `List` of `SheetType`s instead.

```
// An example of how you can iterate over keys and reduce an object to an array
const convertToArray = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
  arr[Number.parseInt(key, 10)] = obj[key]
  return arr
}, [])

// Example query returning the array of SheetType objects
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: () => ({
    getTimeSheets: {
      type: new GraphQLList(SheetType),
      resolve: async () => {
        const apiResponse = await getAPIResponse()
        return convertToArray(apiResponse)
      },
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: What is the field name is `7days` or `24hours` ?

Comment: Names in GraphQL can include numbers, but they cannot *start* with a number. You'd have to map those fields to something like `sevenDays` etc.

Comment: well, write custom resolvers: `{ _7days: _ => _['7days'] }`...thanks