# Using Int as name in GraphQL Schema

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

So, I was creating a graphql schema,

```
type Details {
1: User!
2: User!
3: User!
id: String!
item: String!
}
```

What I want is to use the Int (1, 2, 3) in my Schema but not sure how.
Someone must have been in the same situation before, help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names in GraphQL can include numbers, but they cannot start with a number.

If you need to map over an existing API that returns numbers as fields, you can do a mapping such as this one: [Graphql: How to map fields that start with number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678052/graphql-how-to-map-fields-that-start-with-number)